# data.table optimisation - conditional sum

Tags: r, optimization, data.table

I'm trying to do a conditional sum on a data.table and managed to do it currently in a messy way. I was wondering if it would be possible to do it more elegantly?

Consider the following:

```
library(data.table)
stock_profile <- data.table(Pcode = c(123456L, 234567L, 345678L, 456789L, 567891L, 678912L, 789123L, 891234L, 912345L, 123456L, 234567L, 345678L, 456789L, 567891L, 678912L, 789123L, 891234L, 912345L), 
    Value = c(51.96, 89.64, 21.56, 56.04, 47.56,83.68, 42.21, 66.56, 62.72, 35.00, 3.40, 30.82, 59.83, 82.17, 14.02, 25.70, 81.38, 50.33), 
    Location = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A","B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    NoSales = c("","", "Y", "", "", "Y", "", "", "Y", "", "", "Y", "Y", "","", "", "Y", "Y"))
```

Which should result in the following:

```
Pcode   Value   Location    NoSales
123456  51.96   A   
234567  89.64   A   
345678  21.56   A           Y
456789  56.04   A   
567891  47.56   A   
678912  83.68   A           Y
789123  42.21   A   
891234  66.56   A   
912345  62.72   A           Y
123456  35      B   
234567  3.4     B   
345678  30.82   B           Y
456789  59.83   B           Y
567891  82.17   B   
678912  14.02   B   
789123  25.7    B   
891234  81.38   B           Y
912345  50.33   B           Y
```

What I'm trying to do is to transfer stock from Location B to A and figure out what the total value of stock that has no sales is going to be. So I need a sum of the value of all products with flag Y in NoSales in Location A combined with the value of all products in Location B which have No Sales flag Y in Location A.

So far I've managed the following:

```
# get all NoSales flag Y products in Location A
ANoSales <- stock_profile[Location == "A" & NoSales == "Y"]    
# get all prodcuts in location B 
BStock <- stock_profile[Location == "B"]
# left merge 
NoSalesAll <- merge(ANoSales,BStock,by="Pcode",all.x = TRUE)
# create new column aggregating the value and give the total sum
NoSalesAll[,Value := Value.x + Value.y][,sum(Value)]
```

It works, but is not really elegant. I reckon it should be possible with ifelse perhaps? Any suggestions welcome and appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure how elegant this is, but here it is,

```
library(data.table)

sum(
  rowSums(dcast(stock_profile, Pcode ~ Location + NoSales, value.var = 'Value')
            [!is.na(A_Y), -1], na.rm = TRUE)
  )
#[1] 263.13
```

We can avoid `rowSums` with the use of `.SD` as per @Frank's comment,

```
dcast(dt, Pcode ~ Location + NoSales, value.var = 'Value')[
  !is.na(A_Y), sum(.SD, na.rm=TRUE), .SDcols=-1]
```

Comment: Wow, that just blew my mind, shows me how much more I need to learn. Thank you! (I've upvoted the answer but apparently even though it's recorded, it doesn't show due to my low reputation, sorry!)

Comment: By the way, Sotos, I've noticed that you've edited the title of this question. Am I right to conclude that I should not include "R" in the topic because it creates noise in conducting a search?

Comment: Yes. That is the reason. Since you have tagged it with the `R` tag, then no need for R to be in the title

Comment: You don't need rowSums before sum, I guess: `dcast(stock_profile, Pcode ~ Location + NoSales, value.var = 'Value')[!is.na(A_Y), sum(.SD, na.rm=TRUE), .SDcols=-1]` seems to work. And there's also `stock_profile[, if(any(Location=="A" & NoSales == "Y")) sum(Value), by=Pcode][, sum(V1)]`

Comment: @Frank That's right... Forgot all about `.SD`. Thanks :). You should add an answer with that second option. It looks much better

Comment: @Frank thank you. The second option with any() - just brilliant, this is what I conceptually had in my mind but was unable to formulate in R. Just to makes sure I get the logic right (this is the first time I came across "any()") - does R read this as: "divide the rows into groups where Pcode is the same; for each group check if there is at least one instance where both Location is A and NoSales is Y, and if so - sum the Value of all instances in that group"?

Comment: Yep. This is a side effect of `if (FALSE) x` returning NULL and `DT[, j, by]` skipping by-groups for which `j` evaluates to NULL. There's an open request for more explicit syntax to do this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788

Comment: Thank you, @Frank. I have been experimenting with this setup since yesterday and I'm getting some great results reducing some old code.

Answer (score 2):

I like Sotos [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49211292/8598377).
But if you define "elegant" as an other approach than `data.table`, than the approach with `dplyr` would be:

```
stock_profile %>% 
  filter(Location=="A" & NoSales=="Y") %>% 
  left_join(filter(stock_profile, Location=="B"), by="Pcode") %>% 
  mutate(value=Value.x+Value.y) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(value),sum)
```

output is

```
   value
1 263.13
```

Comment: Thank you, Stephan. This one looks brilliant, too. I need to spend some time with dplyr at some point and get to know it better.

Comment: oh, and as above - I've upvoted the answer but apparently even though it's recorded, it doesn't show due to my low reputation, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my contribution.

```
setkey(stock_profile, Location, NoSales)
DT1 = stock_profile[.("A","Y"), sum(Value),by=.(Pcode)]
DT2 = stock_profile[.("B"), sum(Value),by=.(Pcode)]
DT = merge(DT1, DT2, by="Pcode", all.x=TRUE)
DT[, .SD, .SDcols = names(DT) %like% "V1.x|V1.y"][,sum(V1.x,V1.y)]
```